# Is it possible to create a sidebar that can be hidden in dash?

Tags: python, data-science, plotly-dash

I want to add to my dashboard a sidebar that allows hiding pulsing a button, is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dash Bootstrap Components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/) will give you this capability.

If you just want to add a side bar which is always visible, you can achieve this using Bootstrap [layout components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/).

However, it sounds like you want to be able to hide the sidebar, in which case you should investigate the [Offcanvas](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/offcanvas/) component